# Sorting a list of Image Matrices (Numpy nd arrays) by image size

Tags: python, sorting, image-processing, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a set of matrices as numpy 2d arrays in a list. They are of different sizes (19x19 to 63x63).. Now, I have to arrange them starting from the one with the smallest size to the largest. I am inputting the matrices as below:

```
pics=[]
templates=[]

c1=0
for c1 in range(1,31):
    i1=Image.open("data/"+str(c1)+".gif")
    pmat = numpy.asarray(i1)
    pics.append(i1)
    templates.append(pmat)
```

Thus, templates is the list that has all the image matrices. pmat of course, contains the images themselves. Is there any easy way to sort this?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort a list of images by length, see below:

```
>>> import numpy 
>>> a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = numpy.array([1,3])
>>> c = [a,b]
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 3])]
>>> sorted(c,key=len)
[array([1, 3]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

If your image arrays are all square (ie. x-len = y-len) then this should work no problem for your purposes.

EDIT: If you need more flexibility (for non-square images) you can use `key=numpy.size`.

Comment: sorting by `numpy.size` is more flexible, doesn't require that all matrices are square.

Comment: @COpython I just realized that. I have edited my post as such. Thanks!

Comment: What if I decide to use the image matrix i.e. pmat instead of templates?

Comment: @gran_profaci `pmat` is a numpy array representation of your image. Are you talking about sorting the actual pixels in your image? Or are you talking about sorting `pics`? If you run `sorted` on your `pics` array you should get the same result, although you will need to use something like `key=Image.size`. I am not entirely sure; check the bottom of the page here: http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm

Comment: @gran_profaci Ok, I tested some things. If you want to sort `pics`, you would do it in this way: `sorted(pics,key=operator.attrgetter('size'))`. You will need to `import operator`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry.. yes I meant pics! Thanks a lot for your help. I was able to finally get it right!

Answer (score 2):

what you want to do is sort by `size`...

```
templates.sort(key=numpy.size)
```